# Light inside spaceship doesn't work

Tags: light, lighting

I made a scene with a spaceship, I did put a sun light inside of the spaceship, but the light brightens just the outside, even if the light is inside it doesn't brightens the interior.I already tried with point, spot and area lights; and to flip normals but no result.
Material preview inside spaceship
[image]
Render preview inside spaceship
[image]
Render preview outside spaceship (the light just work in the exterior
[image]
Face orientation
[image]
Can someone help me?

Comment: So is the main issue getting light through a Glass BSDF?

Comment: It was what Dale said. I need to study more before doing posts; just wasted other people time. mb guys.

Comment: No worries, @MichaelNich!  This site is meant for asking questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Blender docs:

A sun light provides light of constant intensity emitted in a single direction from infinitely far away.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/lights/light_object.html

The sun light's position doesn't matter, only the direction and size. You therefore cannot put a sun light inside anything.  You need to use a different light type.

Comment: Also he has to use cycles as the eevee doesnt let the light throu glass shader. If you use cycles rendering and put there a sun your interior will be lighted by it.